# Laravel - Difference between Model::create and save()

Tags: laravel

I've come across two different ways of inserting records into the database, the first being:

```
Model::create([
            'field1' => $request['field1'],
            'field2' => $request['field2']
        ]);
```

and the second way:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->field1 = $request['field1'];
$model->field2 = $request['field2'];
$model->save();
```

What is the difference between these two? Are they the same? When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both do the same thing. See [the create method code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L792) and you will understand. It's just a shorthand.

Sometimes I don't use the create method, for example when I need to set different values upon some condition.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has already been answered. What I've noticed to be the main difference in both are these.

Both does the same thing. It "Saves" data. But create required you to have `$fillable` in your model. Without defining fillable fields, create will not work. The data will not be passed.

However, Save on the other hand, does not 'require' fillable and can store the data in to the table.

Hope someone else finds this helpful. Happy Coding :)